# SDL - Cross platform development

Tags: c++, cross-platform, sdl

I'm going to enter a small game competition in the coming months.  They require the submission to be able to be compiled ( and it will be, before being run/evaluated for the contest) on Linux.  I'm going to be using SDL and C++.  I've only ever developed on Windows before and I've grown quite accustomed to the benefits Visual Studio gives.  I'd like to be able to develop in windows with VS, and then near the end of the process migrate it over to linux.  Beside making sure SDL is already installed on the Linux machine, are there things I can do throughout development that will make the process easier?  Also, the contest rule for all of this states:

***it must also work on an open platform (we strongly recommend making sure that your program run on modern flavors of GNU/Linux, as all of the judges will have access to it).***

I assume compiling/running in Ubuntu (already have a home server with this) would be sufficient for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is slightly open-ended, but my first suggestion would be to use a proper cross-platform build system such as [CMake](http://www.cmake.org) **from day one**. I would refrain from "migrating" to Linux at the very end; you may be under a rough schedule (and maybe run into problems you did not anticipate). Thus, a *continuous* build of (working) Linux versions will help ease your worries.

Furthermore, if the game is meant to run solely under Linux, why not install Ubuntu in a Virtual Machine somewhere and get acquainted with one of the development environments such as kdevelop or qtcreator? Wouldn't *direct* contact with the platform you are developing *for* make things a little easier?

Comment: I don't think that "migrating" to Linux at the end is a good idea. It's not easy to support a few platforms and it's easier to find differences during the work.

Comment: Well, Ideally I would like to have it run in windows.  The contest says that it is ok to run on windows, but has to at minimum run/compile on linux for the judges.  I'm really new to this, so I assume just moving my code over to the linux machine and re-compiling it there is very hard, if not nieve?  I mean, I'd also like other friends to help test the game, or at least play it before I turn it in, and they'd all be running different flavors of Windows.  Ignoring that, would it be best to just do it all in linux from the start?

Comment: @will I don't think that you can simply move the code and recompile. Maybe I am too pessimistic, but there are bound to be some platform-specific differences here, which you should count in from the start. Cross-platform development, on the other hand, would be nice. However, I have no overview of platform-independent toolkits for game development. Maybe some of the other posters can help out here?

Answer (score 1):

I'm developing games and started like you. I'd advise you to use [SFML](http://sfml-dev.org/) library for this purposes. It's not very big and is very good thing to start from.

There you can use:

- 2D renderer (OpenGL)
- Fonts
- Timers
- Wrappers around images/sprites
- Post effects/shaders
- Sound
- Network

In [this](http://sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/) page you can find a few start examples.